# How to define threshold in opencv inorder to get the whole line together including space in python

Tags: python, opencv, contour, image-thresholding

I want to draw a green rectangle on the whole line including space [on this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbssh.jpg)
In order to do this, I'm thresholding the image [in such a way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IunbP.png)

But this is not allow me to get the whole line in contour and unluckily getting an output [in such a way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYTap.png)

Please help me out with this guys!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do dilatation with big width and short height (something like 50 width, 5 height). It will help.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html